Ubuntu 24.04 : The package cache file is corrupted
twice I got this cache error.  I do not recall how I fixed it the first time.  Had done search on internet but some solution did not fix it or could not apply to my situation.
It happened 5-10 minutes after I had purged Chrome that I had installed.
Why is it even happening?
Why does the package have a (1) at the end?  Is it a duplicate file?
browserice:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for browserice: 
Hit:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease                                  
Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease                                
Hit:4 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted

browserice:~$ sudo apt-get clean

browserice:~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted

browserice:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

browserice:~$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# Ubuntu sources have moved to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

browserice:~$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
Types: deb
URIs: http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

Types: deb
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

browserice:~$ sudo ls -al /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110797 Oct 20 15:48 /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages



This question is similar to: My repos became corrupted: Unable to parse package file. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Found in anothere thread to do the followings:
Try a sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* and then run sudo apt-get update again.
The error message is gone.
Now I know what to do when I get this.
But I still did not get an answer why this is happening.  I happened twice in 2 weeks !
